# File Maker Scripting - Sending Different Attachment

Tags: database, email, pdf, filemaker

**Is there a way to send a mail with different PDF file to different contacts using file maker?**

I am aware of sending batch emails with one attachment but I would like to send a personalize PDF for each contact which seems not so simple.

Also

Can I add PDF files to the table itself or would I have to use the path to the file?

Example:
Table 1

```
**Name** [James Brown] [James Blue]         
**Email** [brown.j@gmail.com] [blue.j@gmail.com]                      
**PDFfileAttchamnet** [folder/PDF/JamesBrown.pdf] [folder/PDF/JamesBlue.pdf]
```

So an Email for James Brown would look like:

```
Dear James Brown, please see the attached file.

Attachment [JamesBrown.pdf] {actual file}
```

and

```
Dear James Blue, please see the attached file.

Attachment [JamesBlue.pdf] {actual file}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve it by creating container field in you database and import the pdfs in it.
then you can use **export Field Contents[]** to export it and send it by email [image]

Hope it useful

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to send a personalize PDF for each contact which seems
>   not so simple.

Find the records of contacts you want to include and **loop** among them, sending mail to each one **individually** (i.e. without selecting the 'Collect addresses across found set' option).

> Can I add PDF files to the table itself or would I have to use the
>   path to the file?

You can do either, it's up to you. If the path to the file can be calculated (as in your example), you can calculate it right there in the Send Mail script step.

Note that you can also generate the PDF files during the process itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you would actually like to personalize the PDF document(s)?

This is possible, maybe not very simple, but quite simple. The trick is to prepare the PDF as a form, and then fill the form fields to personalize.

PDF has a native forms data format (called FDF), which is described in ISO 32000 (as well as the older PDF specification documents provided by Adobe, as you can find in the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website).

FDF is a simple structured text file, which can easily be assembled using FileMaker (I have done that routinely for several catalog projects). The easiest way to get going is to open the form in Acrobat, fill in the fields, and then export the data as FDF. This gives you the pattern to "fill in the blanks".

So, you create the FDF files using Filemaker. With them you can fill the blank form and feed the saved document to the eMail system.

Which tool to use to fill the blank form depends on the volume you have to process. Acrobat is not very powerful (and you may end up in a bit of a legal gray zone, because Acrobat is not set up for being used as a service). There are applications which are made specifically for filling out forms on a server (such as FDFMerge by Appligent), or there are also several libraries which have the tools to fill out forms (iText or pdflib come to my mind). These applications also allow you to flatten the PDF, which means that there are no longer form fields, but their contents becomes part of the base.

The resulting file can now be either made to an eMail attachment, or you make it available on a server and send an eMail with the link to the file (which method you will use may depend on security and privacy regulations).

Comment: Why would you take such a horribly roundabout route, when you can produce "personalized" (i.e. record-specific) PDFs directly from Filemaker? And send them as a mail attachment, all at the same time?

Comment: If you are happy with the quality of the PDFs FileMaker creates, you may be fine.

Comment: Do you have any specific issues with PDFs created by Filemaker (actually created by Adobe's engine, licensed to FMI)?

Comment: The PDF was already created by another program that has a lot more detail, text and graphics features than file maker. It is the primary reason why File Maker wasn't used to generate the PDF. It simply cannot handle the work.

Comment: @user308689 "*It simply cannot handle the work.*" Perhaps it cannot, perhaps it can - we cannot judge that without seeing it (the work to be handled). In any case, it has nothing to do with your question, which I believe has been answered?